# What is best to clean mold off PVC plastic window frames?

Tags: cleaning

To remove black mold on window sills right next to the glass pane (as a result of condensation), I usually use a combination of water and dish soap or diluted bleach. Is there another chemical that would work better? Would Rubbing Alchohol (isopropyl) hurt the PVC? Does the bleach hurt the PVC? Thank you for any answer you can give.

Answer (score 1):

Contractors frequently use water with a commercial cleaner (surfactant, alkalizer/chelator like NTA) and added bleach (about 10-20%) to pressure wash vinyl siding on houses. The bleach lasts only several hours because it oxidizes the surfactant, so the mixture must be made fresh each day.

For home use, a little dishwashing surfactant in water plus a little bleach should serve quite well, without doing any harm. Just wipe up with a sponge or rag and don't leave puddles on the windowsill.

Condensation frequently occurs indoors on windowframes in winter when humidity is high. Some people like the humidity for easier breathing. Aluminum window frames are particularly effective at condensation; vinyl can be better, but not quite perfect.